# Local Admin can't start/stop services?

Tags: installation, service

My problem occurs on a Windows Server 2012 R2

I'm trying to install a software which wants to start/stop certain services. For this action it wants a user, one that I specifically created just to control those certain services (Let's call him Service-User). This Service-User is in the Local Administrators group and is in no known way restricted from starting/stopping services.

Now when I want to start the services I get the Error Message that I do not have the permission to start services.

Any idea what I could check to make sure that Service-User has the right privileges to start services?

This installation is just an "update" from an older version, on the old versions I used a different user. Already tried to use that user, but it doesn't have permissions to start services either. I'm completely out of ideas.

Comment: Did you launch whatever you are using to manage the services (mmc/powershell) with elevated privileges?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider yes I started it with administrator privileges. I also tried to start the services through the Service window directly, same result